# What is this mountain next to the Semmering railway called?

Tags: europe, identify-this, austria, alps

There is a mountain next to the [Semmering railway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semmering_railway) in Austria (red rectangle in the image below):

[image: Semmeringbahn]

Image [source](http://www.semmering.at/system/web/GetImage.ashx?fileid=1481095&mode=T&width=1000&height=250)

What is the name of this mountain?

**Update 1:** I suspect it's called the *Pollereswand* or *Polleroswand*. Could not find it on Google Maps. [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/2003932595) says it's a peak with 976 m (3202.1 feet) elevation.

Comment: You can follow the track in Google maps. [Start here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Semmering+railway/@47.6390166,15.8283083,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x476ddf08753b513d:0x1696f5fd671c8532!8m2!3d47.639013!4d15.830497) Use satellite view and 3D.

Comment: While I can't offer up the name, that view is very famous in Austria, it used to be on their 20 shilling note. And the photo is probably taken from 20-Schilling-Blick (https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=20-Schilling-Blick) if thats helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the Polleroswand between Breitenstein and Orthof in Austria. You can find it [here on Google Maps](https://www.google.de/maps/place/47%C2%B039'33.8%22N+15%C2%B048'28.7%22E/@47.6582689,15.8064365,2311m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d47.659389!4d15.80796).